# "In Kontakt, in Zukunft" without article?

Tags: grammar, usage, article

I usually hear

> Wir bleiben in Kontakt.

rather than

> Wir bleiben im Kontakt.

and also

> in Zukunft

rather than

> in der Zukunft

Is there a reason why these words are not used with a definite article? Can we tell in general when not to use a definite article, or are these just specific phrases?

Comment: "in Kontakt" is the correct form according to the Duden. Although both versions are used in common speech.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*In Zukunft* is used in the meaning of *from now* while *in der Zukunft* literally means *in the future*.

> Bitte benutze in Zukunft das Auto. → *Please use the car from now.*
>
> In der Zukunft werden unsere Autos fliegen. → *In the future our cars will fly.*

So *in der Zukunft* is rather used to express a long-term prediction (even if they predicted flying cars to exist next year in *Back to the Future II*).

Unfortunately I don’t know how to give a clear example for the case of *in/im Kontakt*.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are simply fixed collocations. "In der Zukunft" is not wrong, it's just used differently:

> Darüber habe ich mir noch keine Gedanken gemacht. Das liegt noch so weit in der Zukunft.
>
> In der Zukunft werden Roboter den Menschen immer mehr gefährliche Arbeiten abnehmen.

Comment: but in your second example, "In der Zukunft" can be replaced with "In Zukunft". In your first example, it cannot be replaced..

Comment: Yes, but the meaning changes, much as with "in future" and "in the future".

Comment: does it? It can be translated in another way, but I think the quintessence remains..

Comment: @christian.s In the second example, the meaning changes. *In der Zukunft werden Roboter...* means that sometime in the future, robots will do something. *In Zukunft werden Roboter ...* has the connotation that *from now on* robots will do something.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Not necessarily from *right now* but *soon*. Context will clarify.